# How to save date as a variable using azure logic apps in mmddyyyy format?

Tags: regex, azure, azure-logic-apps

i have a logic app that needs an input of date as its variable. I see there is something like day of month from which i can get day but not month and year. Any idea how i can concatenate date in the above format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below expression made the trick formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MMddyyyy')

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatDateTime function:

> Returns a string in date format. By default, the result is a string in
>   ISO 8601 format ("o"), unless a format specifier is provided. For
>   example: 2015-02-23T13:27:36Z: formatDateTime('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z',
>   'o')
>
> Parameter number: 1
>
> Name: Date
>
> Description: Required. A string that contains the date.
>
> Parameter number: 2
>
> Name: Format

Comment: yes but i want the string to be returned just the date in mmddyyyy format.

Comment: Yes, you have to use what I said, for example "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "created": "@formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['edited'], 'mmddyyyy')"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },